# Error-ing out attempting to post a message to discord when a twitter post is made

Tags: python, twitter, discord, discord.py, bots

So the idea is simple, I have a list of twitter IDs, when any of these accounts make a post, I want this bot to take that post, and share a link to it in a specific discord channel. Currently, it tosses an error at me when I make a twitter post.
Relevant Code:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener): #this runs whenever a tweet is posted
    async def on_status(self, status):
        send(status)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener() #sets up the listener
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = auth_api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(follow=[{ids of the accounts}], is_async = True)
    
async def send(postID):
    channel = bot.get_channel(834887013756305490)
    channel.send('https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/'+str(postID.id)) #error happens here.
```

Here is the error:
C:...site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py:54: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MyStreamListener.on_status' was never awaited
if self.on_status(status) is False:
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I have attempted to do this in a non async channel, which gives me an error, and I have attempted to add "await" before channel.send (which is how it worked for sending a message on, say, a command prompt), but neither of these worked.

If anyone has any idea what I am missing here, help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Messageable.send` is a coroutine, it needs to be awaited

```py
async def send(postID):
    channel = bot.get_channel(834887013756305490)
    await channel.send('https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/'+str(postID.id))
```